# Programmatically kill process in an iTerm session

Tags: bash, scripting, applescript, iterm

I'm looking for a way to programmatically terminate the process an iTerm session, essentially the equivalent of `Ctrl+C`. I hoped this would be possible via [iTerm's Applescript support](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html), but I don't see anything in there to accomplish this. Might there be an alternative approach?

Comment: How about `kill -9 0` or `kill -9 $$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes **iTerm** is running with a visible window and a process running in that window.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do a **^C**:

```
activate application "iTerm2"
delay 0.2
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    keystroke "c" using control down
```

Comment: Thanks! I was mentally stuck on iTerm's Applescript options, totally forgot about the approach you suggested.